# Execute only a selected WebFilters spring webflux

Tags: filter, spring-webflux

I have implemented WebFilters for my service. Now based on the path, I am selecting only a few WebFilters to execute at a time.

```java
private List<WebFilter> getSelectedFilters(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    List<WebFilter> selectedFilters = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select filters based on some criteria, e.g., request path, request method, headers, etc.
    if (exchange.getRequest().getPath().toString().equals("/foo/bar")) {
      // Add filters that should be executed for API requests
      selectedFilters.add(applicationContext.getBean(ClientAuthorizationFilter.class));
      selectedFilters.add(applicationContext.getBean(UserAuthenticationFilter.class));
      selectedFilters.add(applicationContext.getBean(DealsTriggerFulfilBannerRequestValidationFilter.class));
    } else {
      // Add filters that should be executed for non-API requests
      //selectedFilters.add(applicationContext.getBean(AuditFilter.class));
    }

    return selectedFilters;
  }
```

When we make a request to the application, the selected filters are working as expected, but after the selected filters are executed, it starts executing the remaining WebFilters as well.

Here is the custom WebFilterChain:

```java
@NotNull
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(@NotNull ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    // execute the specific filters
    if (index < selectedFilters.size()) {
      return selectedFilters.get(index++).filter(exchange, this)
          .doOnError(throwable -> {
            // TODO - handle the error, if any
          })
          .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty());
    } else {
      return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
  }
```

I understand it is happening because of the `return chain.filter(exchange);` in the `else` clause. I tried returning `Mono.empty()` and a chain with empty filter list but it does not seem to be working. As soon as this `Mono.empty()` is encountered, the filter chain is stopped and the response is returned immediately. Any subsequent filters in the chain is not executed, and the endpoint handler method is also not called.
I am looking for a solution such that once the selected filters are executed, the program should redirect to the handler method and resumes execution.

Comment: One of the ways I found a solution is to put some conditional at the beginning of the WebFilter and always evaluating it whether it needs to be executed for this request. Caviet is that all the WebFilters will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution!

Autowired WebHandler in the Selector filter

```
@Autowired
  private WebHandler webHandler;
```

In the custom WebFilterChain, called `handler.handle()` rather than returning `Mono.empty()`:

```
@NotNull
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(@NotNull ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    // execute the specific filters
    if (index < selectedFilters.size()) {
      return selectedFilters.get(index++).filter(exchange, this)
          .doOnError(throwable -> {
            // TODO - handle the error, if any
          })
          .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty());
    } else {
      return webHandler.handle(exchange);
    }
  }
```